# Inserting data into a table that relies on the new records primary key for insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, primary-key

This is the first time I have used a forum like this and have come to an absolute halt with my development. 
I am using MYSQL & PHP

Basically I have two tables in (well more but for this example two is fine)

Installation table
Job table

I am trying to insert data using an insert PHP query that inserts data into both tables, but the installation table requires an id from the job table which is generated upon being saved and is also set to increment.

Is this the best way of doing it or is there another way, If this is the only way of approaching this any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: Once you insert a row you can immediately after call mysql_insert_id() (or mysqli_* if you are using those) and it will return the id from the last inserted row.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to insert data into the Job table, and then you use the ID of the newly-added record to insert data into the Installation table.

Comment: Give the dude some code examples...your saying exactly what he is saying. @Louis: try and see this function of mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php. W3Schools has a perfect simple example for this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with functions like mysql_insert_id or last_insert_id, read the documentation.

Say you have a `id` column in your table_1 which is autoincrement

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (`col_2`, ..., `coln`) VALUES ('val2', ...,  'valn');
INSERT INTO table_2 (`col_1`, ..., `colm`) VALUES (last_insert_id(), 'val2', ...,  'valm');
```